# Get all distinct keys of a nested object

Tags: database, mongodb, object, mongodb-query, key

I have following data in my collection:

```
[
    {
        _id: "2313123123",
        metadata: {
            path: "...",
            value: "...",
            name: "..."
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "2313123123",
        metadata: {
            path: "...",
            name: "...",
            origin: "...",
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "2313123123",
        metadata: {
            path: "...",
            source: "..."
        }
    },
]
```

I want to retrieve all distinct key names of the field `metadata` from my documents.
I want to retrieve `["path", "value", "name", "origin", "source"]`.

How can I query for this? Is this possible with the `distinct` method or do I need to use `aggregate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use an aggregate for this, sadly due to the nature of your needs this is going to be a very "expensive" pipeline to execute. There is no way to avoid iterating over the entire collection and adding the unique keys to the array.

We're going to use `$objectToArray` to turn `metadata` into an array, then `$unwind` it and finally using `$group` we could save all the unique values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      keys: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            "$objectToArray": "$metadata"
          },
          in: "$$this.k"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$keys"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      keys: {
        "$addToSet": "$keys"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bUjG5toO_0b)

Answer (score 3):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
       {
         $addFields: {
             metadata: {
                $objectToArray: "$metadata"
             }
          }
       },
      {
         $unwind: "$metadata"
      },
      {
         $group: {
            _id: "distinct",
            dist: {
               $addToSet: "$metadata.k"
            }
         }
      }
  ])
```

explained:

1. Convert the metadata object to metadata array having the keys as values in k key.
2. Unwind the metadata array of k keys & v values
3. group with addToSet to extract only the distinct k values in the final result.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tjRDmo21Hhx)

helpfull javascript onliner from mongo shell option:

```
 db.collection.find({},{metadata:1,_id:0}).forEach( function(doc) { for (key in doc.metadata) s.push(key); } );uni = Array.from(new Set(s));printjson(uni);
 ["path","name","origin","source","value"]
```